# Oracle SQL Developer - Trying to return products by quarter

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, where-clause

I am trying to return a list of products that only appear in one quarter. I have decided the best way to do this is to I have been fiddling around with my code for a while and tried a COUNT but realised that this wouldn't work as it is counting the number of entries a product has rather than the number of quarters it appears in.

These are my three tables:

```
SALES FACT TABLE
TIME_KEY                      PRODUCT_KEY BRANCH_KEY LOCATION_KEY POUNDS_SOLD  AVG_SALES UNITS_SOLD
----------------------------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ----------- ---------- ----------
22-DEC-13 08.31.18.442000000            2 B1         L19             21542.39    10821.2        100 
21-DEC-10 21.19.37.182000000            3 B8         L5                 65487    32793.5        100 
13-SEP-13 06.36.03.720000000            7 B2         L15             78541.84   39470.92        400 
24-JUN-13 12.21.45.186000000            1 B7         L13                94115    47167.5        220 
18-SEP-07 12.58.06.873000000            8 B2         L2                 54000      27250        500 
11-FEB-11 18.06.08.475000000            8 B9         L6                 11123     5636.5        150 
28-SEP-13 15.06.20.153000000            6 B3         L16             45896.31   23008.16        120 
22-DEC-08 19.34.48.490000000            5 B6         L3              87451.01   43875.51        300 
23-JUL-13 20.08.51.173000000            6 B6         L14                69542      34971        400 
20-DEC-13 22.47.24.962000000            9 B4         L17             21584.39    10872.2        160 
21-DEC-06 19.11.50.472000000            5 B10        L1                 10000      27250        500 
13-MAR-13 14.13.58.555000000            1 B2         L11                62413      31256         99 
06-MAR-13 18.15.40.365000000            4 B6         L10                94785    47542.5        300 
20-DEC-13 23.35.12.683000000            2 B5         L18             52359.19    26289.6        220 
15-MAR-13 19.11.58.459000000            4 B9         L12             66499.84   33299.92        100 
19-DEC-11 13.17.34.443000000            9 B2         L7                 51449    26049.5        650 
14-FEB-12 10.20.20.787000000           10 B5         L8                 66589    33394.5        200 
19-DEC-09 10.09.41.844000000            3 B7         L4                 99125    49687.5        250 
22-MAR-12 19.36.24.790000000           10 B2         L9              62331.66   31765.83       1200 
11-JAN-14 19.18.58.595000000            7 B8         L20             35214.85   17667.43        120           

TIME DIMENSION TABLE
TIME_KEY                             DAY DAY_OF_WEEK MONTH     QUARTER       YEAR
----------------------------- ---------- ----------- --------- ------- ----------
13-MAR-13 14.13.58.555000000          13 WEDNESDAY   MARCH     Q1            2013 
22-DEC-13 08.31.18.442000000          22 SUNDAY      DECEMBER  Q4            2013 
21-DEC-10 21.19.37.182000000          21 TUESDAY     DECEMBER  Q4            2010 
15-MAR-13 19.11.58.459000000          15 FRIDAY      MARCH     Q1            2013 
21-DEC-06 19.11.50.472000000          21 THURSDAY    DECEMBER  Q4            2006 
28-SEP-13 15.06.20.153000000          28 SATURDAY    SEPTEMBER Q3            2013 
11-JAN-14 19.18.58.595000000          11 SATURDAY    JANUARY   Q1            2014 
11-FEB-11 18.06.08.475000000          11 FRIDAY      FEBRUARY  Q1            2011 
20-DEC-13 22.47.24.962000000          20 FRIDAY      DECEMBER  Q4            2013 
14-FEB-12 10.20.20.787000000          14 TUESDAY     FEBRUARY  Q1            2012 
24-JUN-13 12.21.45.186000000          24 MONDAY      JUNE      Q2            2013 
20-DEC-13 23.35.12.683000000          20 FRIDAY      DECEMBER  Q4            2013 
19-DEC-09 10.09.41.844000000          19 SATURDAY    DECEMBER  Q4            2009 
06-MAR-13 18.15.40.365000000           6 WEDNESDAY   MARCH     Q1            2013 
22-DEC-08 19.34.48.490000000          22 MONDAY      DECEMBER  Q4            2008 
23-JUL-13 20.08.51.173000000          23 TUESDAY     JULY      Q3            2013 
13-SEP-13 06.36.03.720000000          13 FRIDAY      SEPTEMBER Q3            2013 
18-SEP-07 12.58.06.873000000          18 TUESDAY     SEPTEMBER Q3            2007 
19-DEC-11 13.17.34.443000000          19 MONDAY      DECEMBER  Q4            2011 
22-MAR-12 19.36.24.790000000          22 THURSDAY    MARCH     Q1            2012

PRODUCT DIMENSION TABLE
PRODUCT_KEY PRODUCT_NAME              BRAND                TYPE       SUPPLIER_TYPE  
----------- ------------------------- -------------------- ---------- ----------------
          1 SVF1521P2EB               SONY                 LAPTOP     WHOLESALER       
          2 15-A003SA                 COMPAQ               LAPTOP     WHOLESALER       
          3 15-N271SA                 HP                   LAPTOP     RETAIL           
          4 15-N290SA                 HP                   LAPTOP     RETAIL           
          5 E6400                     DELL                 LAPTOP     RETAIL           
          6 SVF1521C2EB               SONY                 LAPTOP     WHOLESALER       
          7 SVF1532K4EB               SONY                 LAPTOP     WHOLESALER       
          8 C50-A-1CK                 TOSHIBA              LAPTOP     WHOLESALER       
          9 NX.MF8EK.001              ACER                 LAPTOP     RETAIL           
         10 NP915S3G-K01UK            SAMSUNG              LAPTOP     RETAIL
```

This is the code that I am running:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.product_name, product.brand, quarter, SUM (sales.units_sold), COUNT (quarter)
FROM sales
INNER JOIN product
ON product.product_key=sales.product_key
INNER JOIN time
ON sales.time_key=time.time_key
GROUP BY quarter, product.product_name, product.brand
ORDER BY brand;
```

Below is the result once I run the query with the code that I have so far which is obviously not giving me what I want:

```
PRODUCT_NAME              BRAND                QUARTER SUM(SALES.UNITS_SOLD) COUNT(QUARTER)
------------------------- -------------------- ------- --------------------- --------------
NX.MF8EK.001              ACER                 Q4                        810              2 
15-A003SA                 COMPAQ               Q4                        320              2 
E6400                     DELL                 Q4                        800              2 
15-N271SA                 HP                   Q4                        350              2 
15-N290SA                 HP                   Q1                        400              2 
NP915S3G-K01UK            SAMSUNG              Q1                       1400              2 
SVF1521C2EB               SONY                 Q3                        520              2 
SVF1521P2EB               SONY                 Q1                         99              1 
SVF1521P2EB               SONY                 Q2                        220              1 
SVF1532K4EB               SONY                 Q1                        120              1 
SVF1532K4EB               SONY                 Q3                        400              1 
C50-A-1CK                 TOSHIBA              Q1                        150              1 
C50-A-1CK                 TOSHIBA              Q3                        500              1
```

I know its probably simple for you guys but I can sense that I am nearly there, I think I just have something the wrong way round and am not translating my intention into code.

The desired output would display products that have only been sold in one quarter. If they were sold in two quarters they would not be considered seasonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query `count(quarter)` is going to be the same as `count(*)`.  You need to remove `quarter` from the `group by` and do the comparison on the number of quarters in a `having` clause:

```
SELECT product.product_name, product.brand, MIN(quarter) as quarter, SUM(sales.units_sold)
FROM sales INNER JOIN
     product
     ON product.product_key = sales.product_key INNER JOIN
     time
     ON sales.time_key = time.time_key
GROUP BY product.product_name, product.brand
HAVING min(quarter) = max(quarter)
ORDER BY brand;
```

You could also use:

```
HAVING count(distinct quarter) = 1
```

However, `count(distinct)` is less efficient than most other aggregation functions.